# merging 4 lines in to one

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I am trying to turn this input:

```
A----A----------A----A-A--AAAA
-CC----CCCC-C-----CCC-C-------C
------G----G--G--G------G------
---TT--------T-T---------T-----
```

into the following output:

```
ACCTTAGCCCCGCTGTAGCCCACAGTAAAAC
```

I want to use bash for this. Is there a specific command to do this, or do I need to write an actual script?

Comment: You need to write an actual script. You should really make an attempt to do so yourself.

Comment: I have tried of course.

Comment: Then [edit] your question to show your attempt.

Comment: Where's that 3rd `T` coming from?

Comment: @ne1410s I think the output has problem, the first `CCC` should be `CCCC` if I understood the question right....

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit that, thanks

Comment: @VitalVerleyen and the 4 lines could have different length? should the first line be ended with `-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
line[1]="A----A----------A----A-A--AAAA-"
line[2]="-CC----CCCC-C-----CCC-C-------C"
line[3]="------G----G--G--G------G------"
line[4]="---TT--------T-T---------T-----"

lsize=${#line[1]}
out=""
for (( i=0; i<$lsize; i++ )) ; do
    for ((j=1; j<=4; j++ )) ; do
        c=${line[${j}]:${i}:1}
        if [ "$c" != "-" ] ; then
            out=${out}${c}
        fi
    done
done
echo $out
```

Note that this assumes the input is well-formed -- it does no error checking!
You may wish to use "read" or some other way to get the four input strings in, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
read line[1] < a.dat
read line[2] < c.dat
read line[3] < g.dat
read line[4] < t.dat
 ...
```

And if all 4 lines of input are in a single file, you can redirect stdin and use:

```
#!/bin/bash
read line[1]
read line[2]
read line[3]
read line[4]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped.

Comment: @VitalVerleyen if this answers your question, please mark it as answered.  Thx.

Comment: If you are hard coding those arrays anyway, you may aswell just skip the script and write out the sequence yourself.

Comment: @JohnHascall yes but your answer doesn't do that, and would be quite different if it did. Also you edit assumes all the input comes from a single line in multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

another script without error check (and loops)

```
$ fold -w1 file | pr -4t | sed 's/\s*-\s*//g' | tr -d '\n' | sed '$a\'

ACCTTAGCCCCGCTGTAGCCCACAGTAAAAC
```

ps. Your first line is missing a `-` at the end.

another shorter alternative

```
fold -w1 file | pr -4t | tr -d '\n\t\- ' | sed '$a\'
```

Comment: Whats the last sed for ? Also nice with the fold pr combo!

Comment: the last sed is to add a newline at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Perl

```
perl -ne '
    if ($. == 1) {$str = $_; next}
    for (my $i=0; $i<length($str); $i++) {
        substr($str,$i,1) = substr($_,$i,1) if substr($_,$i,1) =~ /[ACGT]/;
    } 
    END {print $str}
' file
```

same program in awk

```
awk '
    NR == 1 {str = $0; next} 
    {
        for (i=1; i<=length($0); i++) 
            if (substr($0,i,1) ~ /[ACGT]/) 
                str = substr(str,1,i-1) substr($0,i,1) substr(str,i+1)
    } 
    END {print str}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first line ends with `-`, this awk command should work for you:

```
awk 'NR==1{split($0,a,"");next}
    {delete b;split($0,b,"")
            for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)if(a[i]=="-") a[i]=b[i]
    }
    END{for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)printf "%s",a[i];print ""}' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
A----A----------A----A-A--AAAA-
-CC----CCCC-C-----CCC-C-------C
------G----G--G--G------G------
---TT--------T-T---------T-----

kent$  awk 'NR==1{split($0,a,"");next}
        {delete b;split($0,b,"")
                for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)if(a[i]=="-") a[i]=b[i]
        }
        END{for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)printf "%s",a[i];print ""}' f
ACCTTAGCCCCGCTGTAGCCCACAGTAAAAC
```

Comment: Could also do `awk -F '' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i!~/-/&&a[i]=$i}END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf a[i];print y}'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;N;s/^/\n/;tb;:b;s/\n+$//;ta;s/\n-(.*\n)(.)/\2\n\1/;tb;s/\n(.)(.*\n)./\1\n\2/;tb' file
```

This solution depends on all lines being of equal length, however it works for any amount of lines.

Two lines are collected in the pattern space and a newline is inserted at the front of the first. Then each character in the first line is matched with a character in the second line in the same position and if it is a '-' it is swapped. However if it is not a '-' it is left alone and the next character is matched until the every character is encountered (the second line is shortened by one and the position in the first line is bumped along by a character. When all that is left to match are the newlines then the newlines are removed and if another line exists it is appended to the current line and the process repeated.